# Which condition is converted to which boon?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, there are some traits such as [Pure of Voice](http://www.guildhead.com/trait/553/pure-of-voice) and skills like [Contemplation of Purity](http://www.guildhead.com/skill/9248/contemplation-of-purity) that manages to convert suffering conditions into the matching boons.

I've managed to find the matching boons for some of the conditions but not all of them.

So, what's the matching boon for each condition in the game ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**List of Matching Conditions - Boons :**

[image] Bleeding  [image: Vigor] Vigor (9 Seconds)

[image] Blind [image: Fury] Fury (3 Seconds)

[image] Burning [image] Aegis

[image] Chilled [image] Vigor (9 Seconds)

[image] Confusion [image] Retaliation

[image] Crippled [image] Swiftness (9 Seconds)

[image] Fear [image] Stability

[image] Immobilize [image] Swiftness (9 Seconds)

[image] Poison [image] Regeneration

[image] Vulnerabillity [image] Protection (3 Seconds)

[image] Weakness [image] Might (3 Stacks, 9 Seconds)

Comment: I don't think this is a valid answer. Boons do not 'match' conditions. They are separate things, so your answer is subjective and based on your opinion. Granted some do match, just a `Regeneration` against any degen condition, but they are not pairs.

Comment: @DavidYell - The question pertains specifically to traits that convert conditions to boons. If a specific condition is always converted into a specific boon by these traits (as seems to be indicated), then it is reasonable and non-subjective to say they're "matched", even if they don't cause precisely opposite effects in many cases.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could confirm that these traits always convert a given condition into the same boon (as opposed to a random one).

Comment: @sjohnston I've confirmed most of them myself, either with a Thief and Necromancer friend on SPVP or by paying attention to the mob's conditions on world leveling.

Also, DavidYell Feel free to sugest a correction if you dont find the "matching" word a correct approach, but i dont think there is any better way to make the tittle short and self explainable

Comment: Another chart, with some similarities: http://www.noxxic.com/gw2/getting-started/combat-basics/boons-and-conditions. The idea of a conversion priority probably warrants discussion. Yet another chart here: http://blackrabbit2999.blogspot.com/2012/08/guild-wars-2-boons-to-conditions.html; note the reported issue with Blind.

Comment: @MarcelloGrechiLins You've listed Vigor as the 'match' twice, meaning by definition it isn't exactly a match? Maybe try "converted" as in "what is the full list of conditions and their converted boons" or similar.

Comment: @Gwen does it makes more sense now ? English is not my primary language, so, it may look weird